# How can I get return result when I use viewModelScope.launch?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata

I hope to get a Int return result, the code `return mDBVoiceRepository.edit(aMVoice)` doesn't work, how can I fix it?

**Code A**

```
@Dao
interface DBVoiceDao{
   @Update
   suspend fun edit(aMVoice: MVoice): Int
}


class DBVoiceRepository private constructor(private val mDBVoiceDao: DBVoiceDao){
    suspend fun edit(aMVoice: MVoice):Int{
        return mDBVoiceDao.edit(aMVoice)
    }
}


class HomeViewModel(private val mDBVoiceRepository: DBVoiceRepository) : ViewModel() {
 
    fun edit(aMVoice: MVoice):Int{
        viewModelScope.launch {
           return mDBVoiceRepository.edit(aMVoice)
        }
    }

}
```

**Added content 1:**

Is there a simple way if I redesign result type as `LiveData<Int>` ?

**Code B**

```
@Dao
interface DBVoiceDao{
    @Update
    suspend fun edit(aMVoice: MVoice): LiveData<Int>
}


class DBVoiceRepository private constructor(private val mDBVoiceDao: DBVoiceDao){
    suspend fun edit(aMVoice: MVoice): LiveData<Int>{
        return mDBVoiceDao.edit(aMVoice)
    }
}


class HomeViewModel(private val mDBVoiceRepository: DBVoiceRepository) : ViewModel() {

    fun edit(aMVoice: MVoice):LiveData<Int>{
       //How can I do?
    }

}
```

**Added content 2:**

I run your code in Fragment, Code C can get correct result, and Code D can't get correct result, why?

```
 //Code C
//Return correct ID
binding.button.setOnClickListener {
     val aMVoice = MVoice()
     var id=mHomeViewModel.edit(aMVoice)
     id.observe(viewLifecycleOwner){ rowId-> binding.button.text="ID is: "+ rowId.toString()}
}   

//Code D
//ID value return null
binding.button.setOnClickListener {
   lifecycleScope.launch{
       val aMVoice = MVoice()
       var id=mHomeViewModel.edit(aMVoice)
       binding.button.text="ID is: "+ id.value.toString()
   }
}
```

Comment: `viewModelScope.launch {` indicates that this is not a synchronous operation, meaning you won't be able to just return a value from this, you could use callbacks, i'm not sure if there's a better solution for coroutines purely

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't have access to flow then use live data

```
fun edit(aMVoice: MVoice):LiveData<Int>{
   val result = MutableLiveData<Int>()
    viewModelScope.launch {
      val data = mDBVoiceRepository.edit(aMVoice)
      result.value = data //or result.postValue(data)
    }
   return result
}
```

flow version would look like

```
suspend fun edit(aMVoice: MVoice):Flow<Int>{
     return flow {
           val data = mDBVoiceRepository.edit(aMVoice)
           emit(data)
     }.flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)
}
```

this you can **collect{}** in your activity or fragment using the **lifecycleScope.launch{}**

**Edit**:

```
suspend fun edit(aMVoice: MVoice):LiveData<Int>{
   //here return the repository version of the edit
   mDBVoiceRepository.edit(aMVoice)
}
```

now above setup can be directly observed in the activity or fragment inside lifecycleScope.launch{}

or you can modify a bit more to remove the suspend contract.

```
 fun edit(aMVoice: MVoice):LiveData<Int>{
     val result = MutableLiveData<Int>()
      viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
       //here return the repository version of the edit
       result.value = mDBVoiceRepository.edit(aMVoice).value
      }
     return result
   }
```

and observe this directly in fragment or activity without coroutines scope. Adjust minor changes accordingly if needed.

Comment: Thanks! Can I use `withContext()`  in `ViewModel` to get return value?

Comment: this is another way of launching coroutines but again you can't return this directly, in that case also you will either launch in lifecycleScope to direclty access it's value in main or return a live data from viewmodel

Comment: Thanks! Would you please to see my added content in the question?

Comment: Thanks! Would you please to see my "added content 2" in the question?  it seems that  `lifecycleScope.launch{}` can't work well.

Comment: The flow version of the function should not be marked `suspend` (second code block). And in the last code block you are changing the live data value off the main thread, which will throw an exception.