# How to get value from ViewModel viewModelScope.launch without observing it in Activity?

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, android-viewmodel, kotlin-flow, android-mvvm

I am in the process to re-build my live app to use **MVVM and Coroutines** and moving most of the code that is not UI related from Activity/Fragment to ViewModel.

Currently, my app uses **Java language for Activities and Fragment** and **Kotlin for everything new**. The app **minimum Sdk Version is 19**.

In some cases, I implemented LiveData and Live Data Observer in my app, however most of the time I need to get the current value from ViewModel inside viewModelScope.launch without using the Observer in the Activity/Fragment.

For Demonstration purposes, I created a small app that shows what I tries so far.  I am using a log (Timber.d) to show the result in Activity. Unfortunately, the result shows the default values instead of the new values that I expected (10 and 30).

**My goal is to get the current value (10 and 30) in my Activity without using Observer.**

**ViewModel - Kotlin**

```
class MainActivityViewModel(
    private val mainActivityRepository: MainActivityRepository = MainActivityRepositoryImpl(),
    private val defaultDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.Default,
    private val ioDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.IO,
    private val mainDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.Main
) : ViewModel() {
...
  private val _flowWithReturnAndDispatcher = MutableStateFlow<Int?>(-1)
    val flowWithReturnAndDispatcher = _flowWithReturnAndDispatcher.asStateFlow()
    private suspend fun getFlowWithReturnAndDispatcher():Flow<Int>{
        return flow {
            val data = 10
            emit(data)
        }.flowOn(ioDispatcher)
    }


    private val _mFlowValue = MutableStateFlow<Int?>(-1)
    val mFlowValue = _mFlowValue.asStateFlow()
    private val flowValue: Flow<Int> = flow {
        val data = 30
            emit(data)
    }


fun viewModelScopeCollectFlow() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val mFlowWithReturnAndDispatcher =             getFlowWithReturnAndDispatcher()
            val mFlowValue = flowValue

            mFlowWithReturnAndDispatcher.collect { value ->
                _flowWithReturnAndDispatcher.value = value
            }

            flowValue.collect { value ->
                _mFlowValue.value = value
            }

        }
    }
...
}
```

**Activity - Java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
...
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
...
    viewModel.viewModelScopeCollectFlow();

  Timber.d("onCreate-> flowWithReturnAndDispatcher: " +
                viewModel.getFlowWithReturnAndDispatcher().getValue()  + "" +
                "\nflowValue: " + viewModel.getMFlowValue().getValue());
...
}
...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Activity, the problem is that you're trying to get the values instead of observing them. Rarely (or never) should you use the `value` of a StateFlow outside the ViewModel. Flows are intended for collecting. When you try to immediately get the value instead of observing, you're getting the value before they have had a chance to be updated.

Since your Activity is in Java, you should convert your flows into LiveData and observe it in the Activity instead of using `getValue()`.

This:

```
    private suspend fun getFlowWithReturnAndDispatcher():Flow<Int>{
        return flow {
            val data = 10
            emit(data)
        }.flowOn(ioDispatcher)
    }
```

is wrong in a few ways. First, you don't need to suspend to create a Flow. Second, it's against Kotlin convention to create a getter function instead of using a property. Third, there's no need to specify a dispatcher if you aren't calling blocking code or code that requires the main thread (like using `liveData.value =`).

Your `viewModelScopeCollectFlow()` function is convoluted design. You shouldn't have to manually tell the ViewModel to start preparing its own stuff. I would recommend changing it to an `init` block, but even that is really convoluted. You could just be using `stateIn` to greatly simplify your code.

```
class MainActivityViewModel(
    private val mainActivityRepository: MainActivityRepository = MainActivityRepositoryImpl(),
    private val defaultDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.Default,
    private val ioDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.IO,
    private val mainDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.Main
) : ViewModel() {
...


    private val baseFlowWithReturnAndDispatcher: Flow<Int> {
        return flow {
            val data = 10
            emit(data)
        }
    }
    val flowWithReturnAndDispatcher = baseFlowWithReturnAndDispatcher
        .asLiveData()

    private val baseFlowValue: Flow<Int> = flow {
        val data = 30
            emit(data)
    }
    val flowValue = baseFlowValue
        .asLiveData()
}
```

But since you're collecting from a Java class, you should use LiveData instead of StateFlow:

---

Side note, you keep naming things "mSomething" incorrectly. "m" stands for "member" in Hungarian notation (which almost no one uses any more because it's generally considered bad for readability and unnecessary in modern IDEs). "Member" means not a local variable, but a variable that is defined for the whole class scope. If we were to use it in Kotlin, it would only be sensible to use for properties inside classes.

Comment: The whole idea that I try to achieve here is NOT to use the Observer in Activity(Java) for multiple reasons.

1, When the value changes in ViewModel the observer automatically lets you know about it and that can fire up a chain reaction that I do not want.

2, When I change the observer to observe only one time, then I have to create a lot of different one-time observers.

So,  is it any other main-safe way how to get the data from ViewModel without observing it in Activity?
.flow
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63169420/how-can-i-get-return-result-when-i-use-viewmodelscope-launch.

Comment: I don’t understand the requirement to avoid an Observer. It won’t “start a chain reaction” unless you personally start one in your observer. You have to observe or get a callback or something of that sort to know when the value in the flow or live data is ready, unless you want to do something super hacky, like waiting for a certain amount of time and checking, repeatedly, until the value is available. .

Comment: My issue is that I need some information from the database in Activity onCreate. I follow the main-safe approach, but the observer gives me the information after the view is created, so I can't use it in the onCreate. 

Could you advise me on how to get some information from the database using a main-safe approach and then use it in the Activity (Java) onCreate?

Comment: You're describing an impossibility. To be truly main-safe, you cannot wait for the data while blocking the main thread, but `onCreate()` has to complete and return on the main thread. Why do you have to finish everything in `onCreate()` instead of inside a listener? Or is the "chain reaction" you mentioned observers inside observers and you want to avoid that? If that's all your problem is, then you just need to combine your LiveDatas into one inside your ViewModel. See my answer here for how to do that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63529918/506796

Comment: I can see the bigger picture now. I released that the only observer that I needed in the Activity is the observer for the data that will be shown in the recycler view. Everything else should be sorted outside Activity except view releaded data. I try to change the app from Java to Kotlin MVVM so I learn something new every time. Thanks